# 2001 Toyota 4runner - Which wheel is causing "P0500 - Vehicle Speed Sensor A"?

Tags: toyota, 4runner, vehicle-speed-sensor

My 4runner is getting "P0500 - Vehicle Speed Sensor A". What does the "A" mean? Which wheel is that?

Comment: Is the ABS light on? Does the speedometer work?

Comment: @Ben Yes and No. You actually helped me with this problem [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/50338/2001-toyota-4runner-147k-miles-speedometer-dead-and-various-dashboard-lights). I've been getting mixed answers from various people.

Comment: OK, so if the ABS light is on that means one or more of the wheel speed sensors or the VSC ECU it self is bad. This is most commonly a Wheel speed sensor harness issue. Flash out the codes per that other question. You can try ohming the sensor I think the correct reading is around 1.5kΩ, you can find the component test in your service manual. But you should really scope the sensor output.

Comment: @Ben Thanks! Is there a way to know which wheel? I was thinking that "A" may correlate to a some wheel.

Comment: No, any of the sensors failing can cause the speedo to stop working and for p0500 to set. Flash the codes, it'll tell you where to look next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the main vehicle speed sensor (VSS), not the wheel speed sensors. It's a [generic code from the P050x series](https://www.obd-codes.com/p0500). The other P050x codes are specific issues.

Symptoms of a P0500 DTC may include:

- Loss of anti-lock brakes the "anti-lock" or "brake"
- Warning lamps on the dash may be lit
- The speedometer or odometer may not work properly (or at all)
- Your vehicle's RPM limiter may be decreased
- The shifting of an automatic transmission may become erratic
- Other symptoms may also be present

Things which might be at issue are:

- The Vehicle Speed Sensor (VSS) is not reading (functioning) properly
- There is a broken/frayed wire leading to the vehicle speed sensor
- The vehicle's PCM is not correctly configured for the actual tire size on the vehicle

Comment: This helped me find [Testing the vehicle speed sensor](http://www.toyota-4runner.org/3rd-gen-t4rs/127574-testing-vehicle-speed-sensor.html) which has further information for my specific vehicle.