# Where is the "No. 1 vehicle speed sensor" on a 2001 Toyota 4runner?

Tags: toyota, vehicle-speed-sensor, 4runner

I can find diagrams for No. 2 vehicle speed sensor, but I need to look at my No. 1 VSS.

[image: Diagram]

Looking in the [field service manual](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KkFbVP_nNu5Ws3HjvX5nAMKUCbrUWPTI/view?usp=sharing), I can't see it either.

Where is my No. 1 VSS?

Comment: To be honest, I bet they mislabeled one of the two which they are showing in the image. There's the one which is labeled from the top of the drawing, then one in the inset. They look to be at completely different orientation angles. I would bet these are two different sensors. Which is which, I wouldn't know.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I believe that the reason it shows two different VVS No. 2 sensors is for different transmission models. You can see they're labeled A340F in the main picture and A340E in the speech bubble thing. The A340E is for the 4x2 models the A340F is for the 4x4's.

Comment: @Ben - Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

VSS 1 isn't really a sensor. On that car the VSC ECU takes input front the wheel speed sensors and sends a 4 pulse signal to the Instrument cluster. Which in turn sends a 5v square wave to the ECM.

This is explained with a circuit diagram and visual representation in the field service manual you linked in section DI-103.

Comment: Okay. I am getting an error code "P0500 - Vehicle Speed Sensor A" (see [this](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/51181/2001-toyota-4runner-which-wheel-is-causing-p0500-vehicle-speed-sensor-a)). What does it mean? I was told it meant the VSS had a problem.

Comment: @aidan.plenert.macdonald see your other question for the reply.

Comment: Given Ben’s answer, it sounds as if you will need a Toyota compatible manfacturer level computer set up to access that level of information and write to, those systems otherwise even if you read the field service manual And understand how it is working you won’t be able to change anything.